# Can I have placeholder columns in a stored procedure to store future values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to create a stored procedure with placeholder columns. I mean, I am using column names which don't exist in the present table, but these columns will be added into the table later.

Is there any possibility in SQL to reserve placeholders for future entries?

The 2 columns are `identity` and `sexualorientation`, which follow these rules:

```
    For Identity
    If Identity = 'M', display 'Male'. 
    If Identity = 'F', display 'Female'. 
    If Identity = 'x1', display 'Trans Male/Trans Man'. 
    If Identity = 'x2', display 'Trans Female/Trans Woman'. 
    If Identity = 'x3', display 'Genderqueer/Gender Non-Conforming'. 
    For Sexual Orientation, 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x1', display 'Gay'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x2', display 'Lesbian'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x3', display 'Straight'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x4', display 'Bisexual'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x5', display 'Pansexual (or Omnisexual)'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x6', display 'Queer'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x7', display 'Asexual'. 
    If Sexual Orientation = 'x8', display 'Questioning'.
```

This is the code I am trying to use:

```
   select stu_id,case 
            when 'M' then 'MALE'
            when 'F' then 'FEMALE'
            when 'X1' then 'Trans Male/Trans Man'
            when 'X2' then 'TransFemale/TransWoman'
            when 'X3' then 'Genderqueer/Gender Non-Conforming'
        end as 'Identity'
       , case 
            when 'x1' then 'Gay'
            when 'x2' then 'Lesbian'
            when 'X3' then 'Straight'
            when 'X4' then 'Bisexual'
            when 'X5' then 'Pansexual (or Omnisexual)'
            when 'x1' then 'Queer'
            when 'x1' then 'Asexual'
            when 'x1' then 'Questioning'
        end as sexualOrientation
        , it.INDV_TAX_ID
        , it.[BIRTH_DATE]
        ,vt.DECEASED_FL
        FROM DBO.ID0UIT it join dbo.sr0skt kt on it.[UCLA_ID] = kt.[STU_ID]
                           join dbo.si0_stu_attr ar on it.UCLA_ID = ar.STU_ID
                           join dbo.SR0PVT vt on it.UCLA_ID = vt.STU_ID
```

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "*spaceholds*"... are you trying to add a column to your select statement that doesn't yet exist in the table?

Comment: You could use constants like `'M'` as placeholders for where the future columns will go.

Comment: yes am trying to add column that doesn't exist

Comment: I would recommend creating a table to map your codes to a string representation. If you do this in a case expression like this you will have to constantly recreate this. If you put those codes in a table with the description it would be a lot easier in the long run.

Comment: If you select a constant or computed value, it becomes a column in the output, even if it doesn't exist in the source table. For example `select 'A' as sample from ID0UIT` is valid, and will result in a column named "sample" in the output.

Comment: The `case` statements need a value or column to test the value after the `when` against. So `CASE 'TODO' when 'x1' then 'Gay' ...`. Don't forget that you will need some sort of default value (in an `ELSE` perhaps) while you don't have actual values.

Comment: One handy constant is `NULL`. If you know what type it should be you could include a cast, e.g. `case Cast( NULL as VarChar(3) ) -- Future shoe width column.`. An `else` clause on the `case` can catch the missing value and do something appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to present columns named `Identity` and `SexualOrientation` in the output of this stored procedure, and those columns don't yet exist in the underlying tables, and you don't care about what values are in these columns for now:

```
select     stu_id
           ,null as [Identity]
           ,null as sexualOrientation
           ,it.INDV_TAX_ID
           ,it.BIRTH_DATE
           ,vt.DECEASED_FL
from       dbo.ID0UIT       it 
inner join dbo.sr0skt       kt   on it.UCLA_ID = kt.STU_ID
inner join dbo.si0_stu_attr ar   on it.UCLA_ID = ar.STU_ID
inner join dbo.SR0PVT       vt   on it.UCLA_ID = vt.STU_ID
```

This will leave those "placeholder" columns with NULL values for all rows.

If you want to put "real" values in those columns, you have to have some other column or columns you can use to work out the correct value for each row. Without understanding more about the tables in your query, I cannot say if you have that. If you *do* already have that, then you don't really need to create new columns to hold these things!

Note, `Identity` is a SQL Server reserved word (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189822.aspx) with special meanings in SQL code, so it's generally a bad idea to use it as a column name (or name of any other type of object). You could use something like `GenderIdentity` or just `Gender` instead?

Also note, it's good practice to state explicitly which kind of join you're using, which is why I've written `inner join` in my answer. It doesn't make any difference to SQL Server, but is clearer to read.